# Can I combine as series of pipe functions for reuse in more than one task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have this gulp task:

```
gulp.task('make_prod_fl', ['rename_bundles'], function () {
    gulp.src('index-fl.html')
    // common piped tasks here
    .pipe(rename("index-prod-fl.html"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

and this:

```
gulp.task('make_prod_ie', ['rename_bundles'], function () {
    gulp.src('index-ie.html')
    // common piped tasks here
    .pipe(rename("index-prod-ie.html"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

There are more of these very similar tasks.

Is there a way that I can combine the common tasks so as to not have to repeat the same common code many times for each make_prod_xx task that I run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Gulp is just JavaScript there are many, many ways of keeping things DRY in a Gulpfile. Which one you choose depends on your particular use case (and, ultimately, personal preference and taste).

Here's a small sample of how you could abstract away the similarities in your Gulpfile:

1. You can use a function that returns the function for your task:

   ```
   function rn(name) {
     return function() {
       return gulp.src('index-' + name + '.html')
         .pipe(rename('index-prod-' + name + '.html'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
     }
   }

   gulp.task('make_prod_fl', rn('fl'));

   gulp.task('make_prod_ie', rn('ie'));
   ```
2. You can use [`lazypipe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe) to reuse chained `pipe()` statements:

   ```
   function rn(name) {
     return (lazypipe()
       .pipe(rename, 'index-prod-' + name + '.html')
       .pipe(gulp.dest, './'))();
   }

   gulp.task('make_prod_fl', function () {
     return gulp.src('index-fl.html').pipe(rn("fl"));
   });

   gulp.task('make_prod_ie', function () {
     return gulp.src('index-ie.html').pipe(rn("ie"));
   });
   ```
3. You can dynamically create tasks from within a loop:

   ```
   ['fl', 'ie'].forEach(function(name) {
     gulp.task('make_prod_' + name, function () {
       return gulp.src('index-' + name + '.html')
         .pipe(rename('index-prod-' + name + '.html'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Hey Sven - I just have to say that specifically this example I couldn't find anywhere and was hugely helpful:

`function rn(name) {
  return (lazypipe()
    .pipe(rename, 'index-prod-' + name + '.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest, './'))();
}`